# Object fetch same api endpoint

Tags: javascript

I'm creating two instances of this object on every page of my website. When it loads, it
the makes a fetch call to /cities.json for data, that it then stores in session storage.

Next time the object
is created (on another page), it checks session storage before calling the api endpoint, to prevent
needless data requests. However, when the object is first created it makes two calls to the /cities.json api - because two instances typehead exist.

Apart from moving the call to outside of the object creation, which I don't want to do, as other objects also require this same api
endpoint, and I'd like to find a pattern that could work for each.

---

**Index.js**

```
import Typeahead from '../typeahead'

    var typeaheadElements = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('typeahead'));
    if (typeaheadElements.length) {
      typeaheadElements.map(function (element) { 
        new Typeahead(element);  
      });  
    }
```

**Typeahead.js**

```
import fetchPromise from '../utilities/fetchSetStorage.js';

function Typeahead(element) {
  init.call(this);

  function init() {
    var input = element.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    if (input) {

      let citiesData = fetchPromise('./cities.json', 'citiesJson');
      Promise.all([citiesData]).then(function(values) {
        items = values[0];
        element.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].removeAttribute('disabled');
      });

      input.addEventListener('input', handleChange.bind(this));
      element.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown.bind(this));
      element.addEventListener('click', handleElementClick.bind(this));
      document.addEventListener('click', handleDocumentClick.bind(this));
    }
  }
}
```

**fetchSetStorage.js**

```
export default function fetchPromise(url, storageKey) {
  if(sessionStorage.getItem(storageKey)) {
    let storageKeyVal = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(storageKey));
    return storageKeyVal;
  } 

  return fetch(url)
    .then(function(response) {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
          response.status);
        return;
      }
      return response;
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      sessionStorage.setItem(storageKey, JSON.stringify(response))
      return response;
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
    })
}
```

```js
function Typeahead(element) {
  init.call(this);

  function init() {
    var input = true;
    if (input) {
      console.log('input')
      let citiesData = fetchPromise('/echo/json/', 'citiesJson');
      Promise.all([citiesData]).then(function(values) {
        items = values[0];
        console.log(values);
      });
    }
  }
}

function fetchPromise(url, storageKey) {
  if (sessionStorage.getItem(storageKey)) {
    let storageKeyVal = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(storageKey));
    return storageKeyVal;
  }

  return fetch(url)
    .then(function(response) {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
          response.status);
        return;
      }
      return response;
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      sessionStorage.setItem(storageKey, JSON.stringify(response))
      return response;
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
    })
}

var typeaheadElements = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('typeahead'));
if (typeaheadElements.length) {
  console.log('typeaheadfound');
  typeaheadElements.map(function(element) {
    new Typeahead(element);
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="typeahead">
  Typeahead
</div>

<div class="typeahead">
  Typeahead
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: May be difficult as it interacts with sessionStorage - have tried to mock an example

Comment: Ok, but it's kinda hard to help with that much code... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My "dirty" solution:

**Typeahead.js**

```
import fetchPromise from '../utilities/fetchSetStorage.js';

let isFetched = false;

function Typeahead(element) {
  init.call(this);

  function init() {
    var input = element.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    if (input && !isFetched) {
      isFetched = true;
      let citiesData = fetchPromise('./cities.json', 'citiesJson');
      Promise.all([citiesData]).then(function(values) {
        items = values[0];
        element.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].removeAttribute('disabled');
      });

      input.addEventListener('input', handleChange.bind(this));
      element.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown.bind(this));
      element.addEventListener('click', handleElementClick.bind(this));
      document.addEventListener('click', handleDocumentClick.bind(this));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a small suggestion (i may be worng) that "isFetched = true;" must be done inside the "then" callback, because in case of any network issue during first call to fetch data, the data will never be fetched as the flag is already updated but data has never come :(

Comment: @Khyati should not be since if you put inside `then`, `Typehead` components will all fetch data and the 1st one returns result will set `isFetched = true`, which is not correct. To solve your case, `fetchSetStorage.js` must return a proper error and `Typehead` will set `isFetched = false` in catch handler.

Comment: yeah setting the flag back to false inside an error callback makes more sense :)